# Delete an attachment sent in an email between Gmail accounts

Tags: gmail

I accidentally sent the wrong image in an email and it contains sensitive information. Is there a way to delete that file? I know the answer is going to be no because once the email is sent it goes to another server.

But if I have a Gmail account and the person I sent it to has a Gmail account could Gmail delete that file? I really wish Gmail showed a preview of attached files or let me preview the email before sending it.

After I sent it it showed the images inline in the Gmail conversation which is how I noticed it.

Comment: There is no way. You could ask that person politely, not to open the mail. :-)

Comment: What I ended up doing was just mentioning to ignore the last email I sent as I forgot to add something (tried not to make it a big deal). I mentioned it to my supervisor and they said not to worry about it. It happened to work out thankfully...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the discussion here, there is no way to recall a sent email.

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/B3o-rYSMLrY

Comment: I would mention to future readers that Bibhas comment is also helpful